# Cassandra : missing EOF at ')' when trying to create simple table

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to create a simple table on Cassandra using cqlsh.  The syntax is:

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST(
        timestamp timestamp,
        system_id text,
        hostname text,
        cpu_pct float,
        memory_used bigint,
        PRIMARY_KEY(system_id, timestamp)
    );
```

When I run this I get this error however.  How to fix?

```
    ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 8:0 missing EOF at ')' (...,PRIMARY_KEY(system_id, timestamp)[)];)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
        timestamp timestamp,
        system_id text,
        hostname text,
        cpu_pct float,
        memory_used bigint,
        PRIMARY KEY(system_id, timestamp)
    );
```

[See CQL CREATE TABLE Doc](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html)

Comment: The change here is the space instead of the underscore in 'PRIMARY KEY'

Answer (score 6):

You accidentally put an underscore between "PRIMARY KEY" instead of a space.

Also you might not want a field called "timestamp" since that is also a Cassandra type, so maybe call that "ts" or something.

Answer (score 3):

`PRIMARY_KEY()` should be `PRIMARY KEY()`.